# Configure Hibernate C3P0 Connection Pooling

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm stumbled upon a problem while developing a Web Application based on Struts2 with Spring and Hibernate.

When I refresh the site a few times, for example 2-4 times, Hibernate is showing up an exception about **Too many connections**. I've tried to implement C3P0 Connection pool and have some problems with it

---

The **hibernate.cfg.xml** configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/axelle</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">axelle</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">dbpassword</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>    

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}"
      p:connectionProperties="${jdbc.connectionProperties}"/>

<!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The log output is:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
```

and:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
```

And this is how PROCESSLIST MySQL window looks: http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/3959/be69273cc2.png

---

I've set **max_size** of connections to 20, but it seems like it doesn't read the C3P0 configuration from file, cause from the screen we can see that number of connections is higher than 20, or maybe I'm doing something wrong, but where? I really need some help guys, I'll appreciate this, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make sure that you are closing all the connections that you are opening. Thats the basic cause of connection leak

Comment: Sorry, but this is the first time when I try to implement a Connection pool, can you advice how I need to close it? but anyway I'm trying to close all the sessions after querying the database with `transaction.commit();` `session.flush();` `session.close();`.

Comment: Why do you think that c3p0 is your connection provider?

Comment: You are missing `connection.provider_class` property.

Comment: @RomanC I read about DBCP and C3P0 and thought that C3P0 is perfect for me.

Comment: @AleksandrM I tried it, but without any changes

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I added `<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>` property to hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Which version of c3p0 and hibernate?

Comment: Why do you think `hibernate.cfg.xml` is used to configure hibernate?

Comment: @AleksandrM c3p0 is 3.6.3.Final and hibernate is 3.6.3.Final too.

Comment: @DenisHoss I don't know, post spring config.

Comment: @RomanC ok, look, this is my applicationContext.xml http://pastebin.com/ec0J2BQx

Comment: No, edit the question and add it there.

Comment: I can't read either, still haven't included it.

Comment: What a version of the connector j?

Comment: The mysql-connector is of version 5.1.21

Comment: I think you have a version mismatch. Try 5.0.4.

Comment: Nothing has changed, the problem persist

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mention these property in your hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
```

Refer this link for better understanding: [Configuration Properties](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration_properties)

Answer (score 1):

In your applicationContext, instead of using `<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" ...` try using `<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" ...`
The C3P0PooledDataSource will create a wrapped database connection using the specified DriverClassName, url, username and password